Loop R: create multiple matrices, use results outside of loops, save multiple results, alternative efficient solution
Dummy data set composed of Class, Year, Cumulative percentages, Residual (=1-Cum.Perc)



Year
Class
Type
Cum.Perc
Res




1
A
D
0.4
0.6


2
A
D
0.7
0.3


3
A
D
0.9
0.1


4
A
D
0.95
0.05


5
A
D
1
0


1
A
I
…
…


2
A
….
….
….


1
B
D
0.3
0.7


2
B
D
0.6
0.4


3
B
D
0.9
0.1


4
B
D
0.95
0.05


5
B
D
1
0


….
B
I
….
….



Main problems:
I can generate a series of matrices, but I have done using loops. I need some help to find a more efficient solution.
I have found workaround to some steps e.g. attach label to output which I do not think they are robust and need improving.
I am struggling to access the outputs (individual matrices) of the loops.
What I have done so far and issues:
Used loops to generate matrices “X” of percentages and matrices “Z” of allocated amounts.
Created one matrix for each group. Each group is identified by a set of stratifying variables (class is the only var showing in dummy data for simplicity).
Questions:
(i) The matrices are correctly created. However, how can I produce the matrices using alternative options to loops? I cannot figure out how for example to convert my code into a function and then use apply(). Could you kindly help to find more efficient options that are (perhaps) not too complicated hence I can edit and control when necessary, please?
(ii) to apply the same calculation to each group separately I am using the line of command df <- subset(data, Class == k). I need to introduce additional stratifying variables e.g. Type (so I will have e.g Class A & Type D, Class A & Type I, Class B & Type D, etc.). I am thinking of creating a unique ID for each sub-group hence I can just amend the code to say subset(data, NewVar == h). Or is there a better way?
Issues:
(i) I need to export the matrices outside of the loop into:
(i.a) individual separate matrices – currently I have managed to output the export to lists [output.X[[k]] <- print(round(X,4))] but I am not sure how to automatically create separate R objects each containing one matrix (I can manually create one matrix object at a time (like XA <- output.X$A);
(i.b) an excel file – which I have managed to but I am currently  naming the sheets “manually” sheetName=list("A", "B"), but I need to automatically name the sheet based on the name of the matrix as I will have say 40 matrices (when I will be doing it live) and I cannot rely on labels manually attributed.
# Create empty objects for loop iterations
X <- matrix(data=0, nrow=5, ncol=5)
Z <- matrix(data=0, nrow=5, ncol=5)
Y <- matrix(data=0, nrow=5, ncol=10)

# Create empty lists for outputs
output.X <- vector("list")
output.Z <- vector("list")
output.Y <- vector("list")

# Create Class list for loop
Class <- list("A", "B")

# Generate cashflows and apportion corresponding values
for (k in Class){
    for (j in 1:5){
        for (i in 1:5){
            df <- subset(data, Class == k)    # Split data set by Class
            df$Incr <- c(df$Cum.Perc[df$Year == 1], diff(df$Cum.Perc)) # Create incremental values
            X[i,j] <- df$Incr[i+j]/df$Res[j]  # Create cashflows
            Z[i,j] <- X[i,j]*df$Amount[j]     # Allocate Amounts
        }
        z <- (j*2)-1
        w <- (j*2)
        Y[ ,z] <- Z[ , j]   # For combined output of Z and X
        Y[ ,w] <- X[ , j]   # For combined output of Z and X
    }
    output.X[[k]] <- print(round(X,4)) # Output
    output.Z[[k]] <- print(round(Z,4)) # Output
    output.Y[[k]] <- print(round(Y,4)) # Output
}
# Save output to excel
write.xlsx(output.X, file="output.X.xlsx", sheetName=list("A", "B"), rowNames=FALSE, append=TRUE) 
write.xlsx(output.Z, file="output.Z.xlsx", sheetName=list("A", "B"), rowNames=FALSE, append=TRUE)
write.xlsx(output.Y, file="output.Y.xlsx", sheetName=list("A", "B"), rowNames=FALSE, append=TRUE)

Thank you

Welcome to SO.  Please use dput() to post your data to your question and thus make it reproducible.  Are you looking for a base R or other solution (such as tidyverse)?  lists will be your friend.

I am open to suggestions - happy to move away from base R.
I will look into dput() as I am not familiar with it.
Thank you

Type dput(data) into your R session and paste the result here. That will allow us to work with your data to find a solution.

data$Amount is missing.

Here is a possible tidyverse solution.  The code runs, but I cannot check the results as your test data set is incomplete and you have not provided any expected output.
Note that:

I have replaced data$aAmount with random data since Amount is missing from your input data
I have renamed your object T to avoid confusion with the built-in T.
I expect it would be possible to simplify or remove your i and j loops, but I've not investigated to logic to understand what they do.

library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

classNames <- data %>% distinct(Class) %>% pull(Class)

res <- data %>% 
  group_by(Class) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      X <- matrix(data=0, nrow=5, ncol=5)
      Z <- matrix(data=0, nrow=5, ncol=5)
      T_ <- matrix(data=0, nrow=5, ncol=10)
      for (j in 1:5) {
        for (i in 1:5) {
          .x$Incr <- c(.x$Cum.Perc[.x$Year == 1], diff(.x$Cum.Perc)) # Create incremental values
          X[i,j] <- .x$Incr[i+j]/.x$Res[j]  # Create cashflows
          Z[i,j] <- X[i,j]* rnorm(1)     # Allocate RANDOM Amounts
          # Z[i,j] <- X[i,j]*.x$Amount[j]     # Allocate Amounts
        }
        z <- (j*2)-1
        w <- (j*2)
        T_[ ,z] <- Z[ , j]   # For combined output of Z and X
        T_[ ,w] <- X[ , j]  # For combined output of Z and X
      }
      rv <- list(X = X, Z = Z, T_ = T_)
      # Save output to excel
      for (nm in names(rv)) {
        for (cn in classNames) {
          write.xlsx(rv[[nm]], file=paste0("output.", nm, ".xlsx"), sheetName=cn, rowNames=FALSE, append=TRUE)
        }
      }
      rv
    }
  ) 

res
[[1]]
[[1]]$X
           [,1]      [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.50000000 0.6666667  0.5    1   NA
[2,] 0.33333333 0.1666667  0.5   NA   NA
[3,] 0.08333333 0.1666667   NA   NA   NA
[4,] 0.08333333        NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]         NA        NA   NA   NA   NA

[[1]]$Z
             [,1]        [,2]       [,3]      [,4] [,5]
[1,] -0.491124538  0.05833128  0.7204466 -2.875142   NA
[2,]  0.001367319  0.21978352 -0.4906800        NA   NA
[3,] -0.019452265 -0.16353735         NA        NA   NA
[4,] -0.041574018          NA         NA        NA   NA
[5,]           NA          NA         NA        NA   NA

[[1]]$T_
             [,1]       [,2]        [,3]      [,4]       [,5] [,6]      [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] -0.491124538 0.50000000  0.05833128 0.6666667  0.7204466  0.5 -2.875142    1   NA    NA
[2,]  0.001367319 0.33333333  0.21978352 0.1666667 -0.4906800  0.5        NA   NA   NA    NA
[3,] -0.019452265 0.08333333 -0.16353735 0.1666667         NA   NA        NA   NA   NA    NA
[4,] -0.041574018 0.08333333          NA        NA         NA   NA        NA   NA   NA    NA
[5,]           NA         NA          NA        NA         NA   NA        NA   NA   NA    NA


[[2]]
[[2]]$X
           [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.42857143 0.750  0.5    1   NA
[2,] 0.42857143 0.125  0.5   NA   NA
[3,] 0.07142857 0.125   NA   NA   NA
[4,] 0.07142857    NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]         NA    NA   NA   NA   NA

[[2]]$Z
             [,1]        [,2]      [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.241829212 -0.49701146 0.2483202 0.833589   NA
[2,] -0.225186161 -0.14508188 0.2424564       NA   NA
[3,]  0.053169587  0.04484678        NA       NA   NA
[4,]  0.009212982          NA        NA       NA   NA
[5,]           NA          NA        NA       NA   NA

[[2]]$T_
             [,1]       [,2]        [,3]  [,4]      [,5] [,6]     [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]  0.241829212 0.42857143 -0.49701146 0.750 0.2483202  0.5 0.833589    1   NA    NA
[2,] -0.225186161 0.42857143 -0.14508188 0.125 0.2424564  0.5       NA   NA   NA    NA
[3,]  0.053169587 0.07142857  0.04484678 0.125        NA   NA       NA   NA   NA    NA
[4,]  0.009212982 0.07142857          NA    NA        NA   NA       NA   NA   NA    NA
[5,]           NA         NA          NA    NA        NA   NA       NA   NA   NA    NA

group_map applies its argument (a function) to each group of a grouped data frame.  The functions arguments are conventionally .x and .y.  .x is the data for the current group.  y (not needed in this case, is a single row data frame whose column(s) define(s) the current group.
This solution is robust with respect to the number of Classes and (possibly within limits), their names.
Test data
data <- tribble(
  ~Year, ~Class, ~Type, ~Cum.Perc, ~Res,
1,  "A",    "D",    0.4,    0.6,
2,  'A',    "D",    0.7,    0.3,
3,  "A",    "D",    0.9,    0.1,
4,  "A",    'D',    0.95,   0.05,
5,  "A",    "D",    1,  0,
1,  'B',    'D',    0.3,    0.7,
2,  "B",    "D",    0.6,    0.4,
3,  "B",    "D",    0.9,    0.1,
4,  "B",    "D",    0.95,   0.05,
5,  "B",    "D",    1,  0)


Welcome to StackOverflow. This sounds like a homework, and as far as I can remember, in StackOverflow there is a policy of not doing homeworks for others :) . That said, here are some tips for you to follow:

how can I produce the matrices using alternative options to loops?

there is nothing wrong with using loops as you have done. It is valid and fine. There might be a slight performance issue but in your case it does not matter much

how to automatically create separate R objects each containing one matrix

This is easily done using assign(). For example, in the following loop I'm creating randomly generated matrices and assign them to my_matrix_1 to my_matrix_5:
set.seed(12345)
for(i in 1:5){
    assign(x = paste0("my_matrix_", i),
           value = matrix(data=runif(25), nrow=5, ncol=5))
}

You can check the created variables using ls(). Algo you can dynamically get value of variables using get() (kind of, opposite of assign().

I need to automatically name the sheet based on the name of the matrix

This is also easy using writexl::write_xlsx():
# create a list of some dataframes (or matrices)
my_list <- list(aaa = iris,
                bbb = mtcars,
                ccc = AirPassengers)

# write the named list into Excel file
writexl::write_xlsx(x = my_list,
                    path = "myfile.xlsx")

In case you wonder how, it is mentioned in the help of the function (which you can access by running ?writexl::write_xlsx in R):


Thank you very much for your inputs.
This is my first post and I have tried to present in a logical and simple sequence of steps what I am trying to achieve, so it is not a homework

@elec Then I'm sorry for jumping to conclusions. Regardless, I think your code does most of the work, and you just need to add some extra lines to make it do exactly what you are looking for. Of course, one way would be to dive into tidyverse, but that might have some learning curve especially dplyr and purrr (which are very great packages imho). If you are new to R, I suggest strengthening your base R in the beginning.

Yes, I am indeed new to R - as it is work related, I need to produce something that is audit proof. Hence why in my initial post I mentioned the fact I needed some suggestions not too complicated and that I can handle.
Thank you so much for taking the time to respond to my post and promptly providing a lot of tips.
Equally, I am eager to expand my knowledge further so the additional posts tidyverse or other solutions are invaluable
